# Can't understand output of threading example

Tags: c++

I tried to compile [following](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm) code from a tutorial
using an [online compiler](http://www.compileonline.com/).
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long *tid;
   tid = (long*)threadid;
   cout << "Hello World! Thread ID, " << *tid << endl;
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main ()
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long i;
   for( i=0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++ ){
      cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, 
                          PrintHello, (void *)&i);
      if (rc){
         cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   sleep(1000000);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This is the output:

```
main() : creating thread, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
main() : creating thread, 2
main() : creating thread, Hello World! Thread ID, 23

main() : creating thread, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 5
main() : creating thread, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
Hello World! Thread ID, 1
main() : creating thread, 2
Hello World! Thread ID, 2
main() : creating thread, 3
Hello World! Thread ID, 3
main() : creating thread, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 5
main() : creating thread, 0
main() : creating thread, 1
main() : creating thread, 2
Hello World! Thread ID, 2main() : creating thread, 3

main() : creating thread, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 4
Hello World! Thread ID, 5
```

Why is "creating thread, x" written multiple times above? The loop was meant to run once right?
ps. Also when I run this [code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:46c9) on the same compiler, nothing is output.
pps. I slightly changed the example, the example directly was passing `(void *)i` to thread which I didn't like.

Comment: Passing `i` like that isn't going to work. You send a pointer to the same variable to each thread. You probably meant to send different data to each thread.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Good point but I was referring to smth else. I was complaining about that "main() : creating thread, x" is output multiple times

Comment: Right, which is what you _don't_ want. Anyway, I don't know why you get more lines of output than you intended but, strictly speaking, since you're invoking a race condition you could academically chalk it up to UB :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Maybe it is due to online compiler

Comment: Tested on g++ and compileonline.com. Works just fine. I suspect multiple instances of same program are running (probably some processes are running in background?).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: But the value of i will change at least on *some* invocations of the thread isn't it? (in my example)

Comment: @pseudonym27: You have no idea when the value of `i` will change with respect to the execution of the threads. They could all output  `Hello World! Thread ID, 4`. In fact, notice how at the moment some are outputting `Hello World! Thread ID, 5`, because `i` is 5 after the loop ends. That is surely not what you intended.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: out of curiosity you could look at second code snippet for which there is link in my question which is very similar to my code but outputs nothing.

Comment: @pseudonym27: In this code you have `std::endl` performing a flush, but your `printf` version does not do that. The threads exit before the buffer is flushed. [Add `fflush(stdout)`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88d014d474fd2ff0).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ok I'll see also check please answer below by Alex it seems sleep is causing some issues.

Comment: @pseudonym27: I don't really understand that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: neither do I, when I removed sleep, output seems more reasonable

Comment: @pseudonym27 Tried the second code snippet using compileonline.com and was able to reproduce the behaviour (had to add `fflush`). Interestingly it works fine if I comment out the `sleep` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the same code without sleep line. It seems to me that something's wrong with the online tool.

Comment: Yes. It differs between the runs, but that's OK. Remove the sleep from your second code example and it runs OK too. If no output is given hit F5, and paste and run the code again.

Comment: That's to be expected. You pass the pointer to i to your threads. Keep in mind that you can't control when threads will be executed and when they will be interrupted. So the loop increments i value, and your thread shows the i value at that point in time, not the value it had when the thread was created.

Comment: Everything is ok with your code. Just sleep seems problematic for this online compiler.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you pass the same pointer to all threads. The address of the variable `i` doesn't change between `pthread_create` calls.

There are a couple of ways to solve this: The first way is to allocate space on the heap (through e.g. `new` or `malloc`), and pass that pointer to the thread function. Another function, which I really doesn't recommend because it depends on implementation-specific behavior of compilers, is to pass the actual value as a pointer (e.g. `(void *) i`).

The solution I *do* recommend, is to use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead of the POSIX thread functions.

Comment: @pseudonym27: Why is it that you are unable to write out the word "something" in full?

Comment: @pseudonym27: Taking some care over your comments and questions is relevant when you're asking for free help.

Comment: @pseudonym27: The value of `i` can almost be anything from 0 to 5 in any of those threads. The only condition is that thread #2 cannot say 1, and thread #3 cannot say 2 or 1, etc.